# JS Regex - Match until the end of line OR a character

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example of what I'm trying to match:

```
Match everything after this:::
one
two
three
```

```
Match this also:::
one
two
three
___
but not this
```

My code:

```js
const thing = /[^:]:::\n([\s\S]*)(_{3}|$)/gm
```

I want it to match everything AFTER ':::', but end either when it sees ___, or if that is not there, then the end of the text input, $.

It works for the FIRST example, but it continues to match the text after the ___ in the second example.

Any ideas how to make this right?

I'm only interested in the results in the first grouping. I had to group the (_{3}|$) otherwise it creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `[^:]:::\n([\s\S]*)(_{3}|$)` that you tried matches too much because `[\s\S]*` will match all the way to the end. Then when at the end of string, there is an alternation `(_{3}|$)` matches either 3 times an underscore or the end of the string.

Then pattern can settle matching the end of the string.

---

You could use a capture group, and match all following lines that do not start with `___`

```
[^:](:::(?:\n(?!___).*)*)
```

- `[^:]` Match any char except `:`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `:::` Match literally
  - `(?:\n(?!___).*)*` Match all consecutive lines that does not start with `___`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYSQnj/1)

Or with a negative lookbehind if [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) to get a match only, asserting not `:` to the left

```
(?<!:):::(?:\n(?!___).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NNinEH/1)

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why my code didn't work?

Comment: @Raven I have added an explanation why your pattern did not yield the expected result.